# SP_RENAME doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called **patient** and it contains a Column called **IdP**.

I'm trying to rename **IdP** to **ID** with 
this code:

```
EXECUTE sp_RENAME 'patient.IdP' , 'ID', 'COLUMN'
```

[image]

but won't work

[image: the error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work.  `sp_rename` is SQL Server syntax.

For MySQL, use `RENAME TABLE`, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) to rename a table.  Or `ALTER TABLE`, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) to rename a column:

```
alter table patient.idp change column idP id <whatever the type is>;
```